# Error while finding the max element position in the list in python language?(value error)

Tags: python, list

***ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence***
why am i getting the above error by this code
n=l.index(max(l))
need to find the position of the max element in the list.
l is the list of the elements

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, check the rest of your code. Note that it sounds as if you want to find the index for the maximum value, so you should use `max(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)`, but only if `l` is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error, if I try:
l = []
l.index(max(l))

So, your list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

List l is empty [].  Add some elements, and it should work.